# How to create a signature from Private Key? - DSA

Tags: .net, vb.net, dsa

I am trying to create a signature from a private key that i have been provided and a hashed value. I am using DSA and the following code but receive the following error:

Invalid type specified.
source mscorlib

The error is thrown on this line: ImportCspBlob(pk)

```
 Private Function key() As String

        Dim privatekey As String = "-----BEGIN DSA PRIVATE KEY-----" _
        & "Key Data"
        & "-----END DSA PRIVATE KEY-----"

        Dim dsa As DSACryptoServiceProvider = New DSACryptoServiceProvider()
        Dim pk As Byte() = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(privatekey)

        dsa.ImportCspBlob(pk)
        Dim st As Byte() = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("THIS IS THE HASH STRING")))
        Dim signedValue As Byte() = dsa.SignHash(st, "SHA1")

        Return Encoding.ASCII.GetString(signedValue)

    End Function
```

Can anyone tell me if I am on the right lines herE or  am I way out?

Any help on this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using, as private key, a PEM-encoded object in a format which is mostly specific to OpenSSL. At its root, it is an ASN.1-based structure, encoded in DER, then re-encoded in Base64 (to make it ASCII-compatible), and finally equipped with some headers (the "BEGIN DSA PRIVATE KEY"). On the other hand, `ImportCsbBlob()` expects a bunch of bytes compatible with what [CryptoAPI expects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa381988%28v=VS.85%29.aspx): a custom, Microsoft-specific encoding of the DSA key elements.

I have used an awful lot of acronyms in the paragraph above in order to underline the fact that converting from one encoding to another *is* a complex matter. Those things are heavily layered and very different from each other.

[This blob post](http://pumka.net/2009/12/19/reading-writing-and-converting-rsa-keys-in-pem-der-publickeyblob-and-privatekeyblob-formats/) seems to tell that some very recent versions of [OpenSSL](http://www.openssl.org/) can do the conversion for you.